# Known limitations: maximum cluster size

Tags: cockroachdb

So, after stumbling over some serious limitations with Cloud Spanner (no ORM for python, no update-by-query, index can not join to it's data table to fetch additional values) we are looking into another solution. CockroachDB looks like a good fit, except for a known limitation.

The [FAQ](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/v1.1/known-limitations.html#maximum-cluster-size) states under "New limitations":

> A limitation in v1.1 prevents meta2 from being split; thus, the max size of a single range, 64MiB by default, limits the overall size of a cluster to 64TB. Clusters beyond this size will experience problems.

- do replicas count toward the cluster size?
- will this limitation be removed in 1.2?
- if this limitation will persist for a longer while: what kind of problems will a bigger cluster face?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limitation is applied to the metadata about ranges, so I believe the 64TB number is with replication factored in.

The `meta2` split issue has been resolved in v1.2-alpha.20171026 ([release notes](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/releases/v1.2-alpha.20171026.html), see the first entry under "Bug Fixes"), lifting the limitation.

We are still a few months away from releasing 1.2. If you need to reach this size before then, please let us know and we can figure out what can be done with 1.1.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I doubt/hope we won't reach 64TB too soon, even with google's app engine scaling exceptional, there will always be another bottleneck :-)